# On button action NSNotificationCenter Rises again the keyboard

Tags: keyboard-events, nsnotificationcenter

I am not able to sort of where is the mistake in my code . When i click the *"Submit"* button then the keyboard rises again. Here i am using the `NSNotificatioCenter` which scrolls the view according to keyboard height.

Have a look on code below.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    // Register for the events
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (keyboardDidShow:) name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (keyboardDidHide:) name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

    // Setup content size
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_WIDTH,SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_HEIGHT);

    keyboardVisible = NO;
}


-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    NSLog (@"Unregister for keyboard events");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void) keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *)notif 
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard is visible");
    // If keyboard is visible, return
    if (keyboardVisible) {
        NSLog(@"Keyboard is already visible. Ignore notification.");
        return;
    }

    // Get the size of the keyboard.
    NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];
    NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

    // Save the current location so we can restore
    // when keyboard is dismissed
    offset = _scrollView.contentOffset;

    // Resize the scroll view to make room for the keyboard
    CGRect viewFrame = _scrollView.frame;
    viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    _scrollView.frame = viewFrame;

    CGRect textFieldRect = [activeView frame];
    textFieldRect.origin.y += 10;
    [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"ao fim");
    // Keyboard is now visible
    keyboardVisible = YES;
}

-(void) keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *)notif {
    // Is the keyboard already shown
    if (!keyboardVisible) {
        NSLog(@"Keyboard is already hidden. Ignore notification.");
        return;
    }

    // Reset the frame scroll view to its original value
    _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_WIDTH, SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_HEIGHT);

    // Reset the scrollview to previous location
    _scrollView.contentOffset = offset;

    // Keyboard is no longer visible
    keyboardVisible = NO;

}

-(BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView*)textView {
    activeView = textView;
    return YES;
}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    if(textView == _textViewFeedback)
        [_textViewFeedback resignFirstResponder];
    else
        [_textViewEmail resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}


- (IBAction)BtnActionSubmitFeedback:(id)sender {
    _textViewEmail.text = nil;
    _textViewFeedback.text = nil;
    NSString *errorMessage = [self validateForm];
    if (errorMessage) {
        showAlert(@"Warning", errorMessage, nil, nil, @"Dismiss");
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a delegate of UITextField

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Now set your `textField.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad`

Add this delegate method to dismiss Keyboard

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

OR

You may Put `[self.view endEditing:YES];` in your Submit button action to dismiss Keyboard.

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES];  
Thank You for reply .
 It works for me but still it scrolls the view after dismiss

Comment: then you can reset the scrollview in submit button action too.

Comment: I guess your `KeyboardShow` notification is firing after submit button. May be it is not settled up properly.

Comment: ya i was thinking that only but how to stop it after clicking on submit button

Comment: here is the method:

- (NSString *)validateForm {
    NSString *errorMessage;
    
    NSString *regex = @"[^@]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+";
    NSPredicate *emailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
    
    if (![emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:self.textViewEmail.text]){
        errorMessage = @"Please enter a valid email address";
            }
    return errorMessage;
}

Comment: it looks fine. if your project is not confidential you may create a zip file of it and send it to me.

Comment: Thnx for help Zubair ...
but cant give you the zip its confidential sorry :)

Comment: Can you suggest me any procedure to scroll keyboard on the basis of textview height or any better solution you have ..
Here i am having 2 text view and one buttom at the bottom which gets hide .